# How to make countdown start after clicking a button using local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

```
if(localStorage.getItem("total_seconds")){
    var total_seconds = localStorage.getItem("total_seconds");
} 
else {
        var total_seconds = 6*10;
} 
var minutes = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
var seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);

function countDownTimer(){
    if(seconds < 10){
        seconds= "0"+ seconds ;
    }
    if(minutes < 10){
        minutes= "0"+ minutes ;
} 
document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML = "Time Left :"+minutes+"minutes"+seconds+"seconds";
    if(total_seconds <= 0){
        setTimeout("document.quiz.submit()",1);
        
    } else {
        total_seconds = total_seconds -1 ;
        minutes = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
        seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);
        localStorage.setItem("total_seconds",total_seconds)
        setTimeout("countDownTimer()",1000);
} 
} 
setTimeout("countDownTimer()",1000);
```

Here is the countdown code I copied, I want this counter to start after button is clicked but I can't seem to succed I couldn't find a way to put the onclick working function would be good if I could receive some suggestions and tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your last line `setTimeout(countDownTimer(),1000);` inside a function of an `onclick` event; If you've specified `onclick' as an attribute in the html of the button, it's value should be set to the name of the function you've put it inside:

```
<button onclick="startTimer();">start</button>
```

where your js has

```
function startTimer (){
  setTimeout(countDownTimer,1000);
}
```

alternatively, put `setTimeout(countDownTimer,1000);` inside an event listener for the button:

```
let buttonElement = document.getElementById(<id attribute of button>);

buttonElement.addEventListener('click', () {setTimeout(countDownTimer,1000)});
```

Also, get rid of the quotes around `countDownTimer()` - it is a function, not a string. The function name inside `setTimeout` should not have `()`, just the function name.
Lastly, `setTimeout` will trigger once, after the time argument. If you need it to run every 1000 ms, use `setInterval` instead.

To resume the timer automatically when the user returns, modify the initial if block as follows:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("total_seconds")){
    var total_seconds = localStorage.getItem("total_seconds");
    // start timer from here as storage was found;
    startTimer ();
} 
else {
        var total_seconds = 6*10;
}
```

That way, a call is made to start the timer if a value was found in storage, indicating a previous visit. You might want to include some check on what the value is uncase it already reached zero, but the rest of your code may take care of that anyway.

Comment: sorry for multiple edits, I'd missed several typos when I copied and pasted parts of your code.

Comment: It's only countdowning once I click the button I want it to show how much time left after the users closes and opens the website again

Comment: No worries you helped me out, and I understand too I am not a totally begginer in js just haven't studied abt local  and session storage

Comment: The storage part looks ok, although I haven't tried to run it. If I understand correctly, you want to initiate the countdown with a click (the bit I've answered). Then, if the user leaves the page and returns, have the countdown resume. Do you want it to resume automatically, or wait for another click when they return?

Comment: I want it to resume automatically yes the code has been working fine just want to resume the time after user returns

Comment: OK, will add an update. You just need to put a call to the  `startTimer ()` wrapper function in your initial `if` block.

Comment: I don't quite get it! Can you explain in easier word

Comment: `startTimer` can be anywhere in your code (global scope and hoisting makes it available if called before its defined). It will get called from your click event on first visit and, now with the addition I suggested, from the `if` block that checks local storage, if it finds a value set in the previous visit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did it but as you said I removed the functions countDownTimer() as a string but the timer didn't ran but again when I marked countdown() as "countDownTimer()" (as a string) it works can you tell me logic beyond it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243091/discussion-between-gaito-uchiha-and-dave-pritlove).